# How to receive notifications based on affected person in Rollbar

Tags: rollbar

I'm wondering if there's an appropriate way to receive notifications (email, slack, or even a sound notification, etc...) whenever a Rollbar error is created for a very specific Affected Person/People.

For example, let's say I wanted a notification whenever `dean` had a new occurrence of an error. Would that be something that's best done in Rollbar itself or is there a script that / API that I can call that could do all of this?

Rollbar Affected People Page - https://rollbar.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/Screen_Shot_2021-03-10_at_10.19.49_AM.png

Answer (score 0):

In Rollbar, you can set notification rules to filter by any parameters in the data you send, including the affected person.

Here's an example rule to send an email to Rollbar user "brianr" (that's me) whenever the person "dean" experiences an occurrence level "error" and above:

[image: Screenshot of example Every Occurrence rule filtering on person.username]

In the Rollbar UI, this can be set up at [Project Settings] > Notifications  > [Name of channel where you want the notification] > add a rule and then configure with filters as shown above. The part that filters on person is the `path` filter with path `body.person.username` and value `dean`.

It's also possible to configure these rules via the Rollbar API, using e.g. [PUT /api/1/notifications/email](https://explorer.docs.rollbar.com/#tag/Notifications/paths/%7E1api%7E11%7E1notifications%7E1email/put)